# Self-made queue priority policy for Simulation with Simmer in R

Tags: r, simulation, scheduling, priority-queue

I want to simulate a planning process in R. I found out that I have to use the simmer package for simulation in R.

When the tasks arrive in my simulation, they all arrive on the 'Waiting List'. The tasks that have to be scheduled have different priorities and characteristics. Deciding which task is going to be scheduled, should depend on a 'weight'. This weight depends on the number of days it waits in the Waiting List and the priority. But I can only find the priority-function that needs a pre-defined priority-value (and my weight gets higher when the task is longer in the Waiting List).

I hope that it's possible to make a function, based on information in the attributes of an arrival, that decides which task has to be scheduled. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

With kind regards, 
Roos

Answer (score 0):

Priorities are static, but there's a trick you can do to recompute all the priorities based on that weight or other attributes. The idea is that arrivals should subscribe to a signal that triggers priority recalculation, which should be raised by the arrival that is going to release the resource. The key activity is `renege_if()`, which causes an arrival to leave a queue and follow a signal handler. For example:

```r
traj <- trajectory() %>%
  # ... 
  renege_if(
    "recompute priority",
    out = trajectory() %>%
      set_prioritization(function() {
        # check attributes using get_attribute()
        # then, return the new prioritization values
      }) %>%
      # go 2 steps back to renege_if
      rollback(2)) %>%
  seize("your resource") %>%
  renege_abort() %>%
  timeout(some_task) %>%
  # trigger this before releasing the resource
  send("recompute priority") %>%
  timeout(0) %>%
  release("your resource") %>%
  # ...
```

Every arrival subscribes to the signal "recompute priority" and tries to seize the resource. Those in the queue, will receive the signal eventually, will follow the signal handler to set the new priority and then will rollback to the same situation as before: they susbscribe to the signal again and enter the queue. But now the resource is released, so the one with the highest priority will seize the resource.

Update: See [this section](https://r-simmer.org/articles/simmer-06-queueing.html#custom-service-policies-1) about the implementation of custom service policies.